# XML Data binding wizard and using multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, xml-parsing

I'm trying to use the XML data binding wizard in Delphi Seattle to generate interfaces for a given set of XSD files. I know there are problems with using multiple namespaces in the XML wizard but I cant get 'myself to understand the exact problem / solution....

Before providing you with the extensive details, in brief my question is: How to alter the generated code to make it interpret namespace prefixes that are different in the resulting XML as they are in the XSD definition?

The XSDs from which the code is generated are as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="application/registration/2014/04" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:rmrds="datamodel/canonical/datastructures/2014/01/">

    <import schemaLocation="CanonicalDataModel/CanonicalDataModel_DataStructures.xsd" namespace="datamodel/canonical/datastructures/2014/01/">
    </import>

    <element name="ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="registrationResponse" type="rmrds:AppInstanceRegistrationType" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

This XSD references the datastructures namespace with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="datamodel/canonical/datastructures/2014/01/"
    xmlns:rmrds="datamodel/canonical/datastructures/2014/01/" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:rmrbt="datamodel/canonical/basetypes/2014/01/" xmlns:rmrst="datamodel/canonical/simpletypes/2014/01/">

    <import schemaLocation="CanonicalDataModel_BaseTypes.xsd" namespace="datamodel/canonical/basetypes/2014/01/" />
    <import schemaLocation="CanonicalDataModel_SimpleTypes.xsd" namespace="datamodel/canonical/simpletypes/2014/01/" />

    <complexType name="AppInstanceRegistrationType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="key" type="string" />
            <element name="secret" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

Note: This XSD references other XSD like `basetypes` and `simpletypes` but these are not used in the ApplicationregistrationType element that is the problem here

The generated code looks like this (only relevant portions shown)

```
type

  IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse = interface;
  IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds = interface;

  IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{045B5E7C-83E2-4DB3-B7CD-7C2C28E0E387}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_RegistrationResponse: IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds;
    { Methods & Properties }
    property RegistrationResponse: IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds read Get_RegistrationResponse;
  end;

  IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds = interface(IXMLNode)
    ['{2C1869A9-8B9E-4EC1-9320-5F6683BCB20E}']
    { Property Accessors }
    function Get_Key: String;
    function Get_Secret: String;
    procedure Set_Key(Value: String);
    procedure Set_Secret(Value: String);
    { Methods & Properties }
    property Key: String read Get_Key write Set_Key;
    property Secret: String read Get_Secret write Set_Secret;
  end;

  TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse = class;
  TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds = class;

  TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse = class(TXMLNode, IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse)
  protected
    { IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse }
    function Get_RegistrationResponse: IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

{ TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds }

  TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds = class(TXMLNode, IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds)
  protected
    { IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds }
    function Get_Key: String;
    function Get_Secret: String;
    procedure Set_Key(Value: String);
    procedure Set_Secret(Value: String);
  end;

{ Global Functions }

function GetApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
function LoadApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse(const FileName: string): IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
function NewApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse: IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;

const
  TargetNamespace = 'application/registration/2014/04';

implementation

{ Global Functions }

function GetApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse', TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse, TargetNamespace) as IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
end;

function LoadApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse(const FileName: string): IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse', TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse, TargetNamespace) as IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
end;

function NewApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse: IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse', TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse, TargetNamespace) as IXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse;
end;

{ TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse }

procedure TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse.AfterConstruction;
begin
  RegisterChildNode('registrationResponse', TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds);
  inherited;
end;

function TXMLApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse.Get_RegistrationResponse: IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['registrationResponse'] as IXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds;
end;

{ TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds }

function TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds.Get_Key: String;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['key'].NodeValue;
end;

procedure TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds.Set_Key(Value: String);
begin
  ChildNodes['key'].NodeValue := Value;
end;

function TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds.Get_Secret: String;
begin
  Result := ChildNodes['secret'].NodeValue;
end;

procedure TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds.Set_Secret(Value: String);
begin
  ChildNodes['secret'].NodeValue := Value;
end;
end.
```

The REST service provides me with the following answer XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns10:ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse 
   xmlns="datamodel/financial/modelobjects/2014/01/"
   xmlns:ns3="canonical/basetypes/2014/01/"
   xmlns:ns5="datamodel/canonical/datastructures/2014/01/"
   xmlns:ns6="datamodel/canonical/simpletypes/2014/01/" 
   xmlns:ns10="application/registration/2014/04" 

  <ns10:registrationResponse>
    <ns5:key>cac7bacc</ns5:key>
    <ns5:secret>NzY2MDkwNzliNjJkZTE1MWRjNGViNTI4MTk4MmZjZDkzYzhmY2UwNDA5YmJhMjlhYzVlY2JjZGFmNWE1NDg2OA==</ns5:secret>
  </ns10:registrationResponse>
</ns10:ApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse>
```

When I create an instance with `GetApplicationInstanceRegistrationResponse(XML)` trying to get the value of Key or Secret gives an OLEVariant error, because the `ChildNodes['key']` statement in `TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds.Get_Key` cannot find the node. When I use `ChildNodes['ns5:key']` it works but the `ns5` is not a fixed namespace prefix.

I've already accepted that the code generated by the wizard has to be altered manually, as an extensive search on the net didn't provide me with any structural solution on fixing the wizard results.

So how can I fix this and make the `TXMLAppInstanceRegistrationType_rmrds` aware that its elements are defined in the `datastructure` schema?